# How does JToolBarHelper method work?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to understand for few weeks that how JtoolBarHelper methods work.

You can see the methods called in view class like this:

```
JToolBarHelper::addNew('controllername.methodname');
```

Here, the JToolBarHelper's addNew method uses like this:

```
public static function addNew($task = 'add', $alt = 'JTOOLBAR_NEW', $check = false)
{
    $bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
    // Add a new button.
    $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'new', $alt, $task, $check);
}
```

So, now checking into JToolBar's getInstance method:

It returns the `new JToolBar($name);`. I have also insured to check in the constructor function. But nowhere I could find how addNew() method parameter is separated ie. how Joomla knows that the name before the dot is controller name and the name after is its method name.

I also checked with javascript code for `Joomla.submmitbutton('controllername.methodname');` but could not find.

So, my question is how the parameter passed into JToolBarHelper method knows it is controller name before the dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This controller splitting is handled by Joomla core Controller files. The file path are different based on versions.

JControllerLegacy will be defined in either `libraries/joomla/controller/legacy.php`, `libraries/cms/controller/legacy.php`, or `libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php`. in latest Joomla versions.

Older versions used `/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php`

Hope, it makes sense!

Comment: Sorry, I already know that. But wanted to know how task is split into controller name and method name. can you please point to the file that does this?

Comment: the core controller path are different according to different Joomla version, latest versions using `libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php` method `getInstance()`

Comment: Do you have joomla 2.5 ?

Comment: check this path too /libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php I'm not sure

Comment: Hmmm! Its there. Can you please update your answer with this that how this is reached over there?

Comment: Or, I will investigate it myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yea updated. try to avoid Core file customization it will lost once you update new versions

Comment: I am not trying to update but trying to understand how it works... that solved.